# Detect when app notifications are turned on/off in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to figure out if there is a way how to detect when user turned on/off notifications for my app.

I was trying following code but the listener doesn't seem to trigger, although the OP value actually changed:

```
val appOpsManager: AppOpsManager = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
appOpsManager.startWatchingMode("android:post_notification", context.packageName) { op, _ -> 
    Log.d("foo", "$op value changed")
}
```

Comment: How did you test this? Also your app might be stopped when user enables/disables notifications

Comment: Sergei Kozelko - I simply registered the listener and then launched an Intent leading to notification settings with a background service active. Such approach worked to me for permissions like Usage Access, but it's not triggering for notifications.